# Show specific content based on current user session PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, session

My question is how to display specific content based on user session php.

I have a file called profile.php. When a user click on another user the first user gets redirected to the profile.php file. In this file I want the users to be able to see all the posts that user has made.

**Image illustration:**
[image]

Something like this:

```
<?php 

if ($_SESSION['username'] == ($_GET[‘id’])) { 

//DISPLAY rows with info from Database just like the attached code.

//DISPLAY edit button ONLY if the current user session is the same as the current id of the profile page.
} 

?>
```

**profile.php code below:**

```
<?php 

session_start();
require('connect.php');
if (@$_SESSION["username"]) {

 ?>

 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
    <title>Profile page</title>
 </head>
 <body>
<?php include('header.php'); ?>

<center>
<?php echo '<table border="1px;">'; ?>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span>ID</span>
        </td>

        <td width="400px" style="text-align: center;">
            Name
        </td>

        <td width="80px" style="text-align: center;">
            Creator
        </td>

        <td width="80px" style="text-align: center;">
            Date
        </td>
        <td width="80px" style="text-align: center;">
            Edit
        </td>

    </tr>

</center>

</body>
</html>

<?php



if (@$_GET['id']) {
    $check_d = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id ='".$_GET['id']."'");

    while ($row_d = mysql_fetch_assoc($check_d)) {

        echo "<h1>Post made by: ".$row_d['username']."</h1>";

        $check_u = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM topics WHERE topic_creator='".$row_d['username']."'");
                while ($row_u = mysql_fetch_assoc($check_u)) {
                    $id = $row_u['topic_id'];
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>".$row_u['topic_id']."</td>";
                    echo "<td><a href='topic.php?id=$id'>".$row_u['topic_name']."<br /></a></td>";
                    echo "<td>".$row_u['topic_creator']."<br /></td>";
                    echo "<td>".$row_u['date']."<br /></td>";


                    echo "<td><a href='edit.php?edit=$id'>Edit</a><br /></td>";


                    echo "</tr>";
                }
    }
}



 echo "</table>";

if (@$_GET['action'] == "logout")   {
    session_destroy();
    header("Location: login.php");
}

}else {
    echo "You must be logged in.";
}

  ?>
```

If anyone knows how to solve this I would be most grateful!

Most of the answers I could find online involves user level distribution where the admin and user levels are predetermined. This is not what I would prefer. I simply would like the current user that is logged in to be able to edit their own posts, but not the other user posts.

I hope that this made sense, but if not, just ask!

**Thanks beforehand! 
// E.**

Comment: Note: `mysql_` functions are deprecated. Use `mysqli` or PDO. Don't concatenate values from the user into SQL strings, use parameters. Otherwise your system is vulnerable to injection attacks.

Comment: First of all, Change `($_GET[‘id’])) { ` to `($_GET['id'])) { ` in `if ($_SESSION['username'] == ($_GET[‘id’])) { `

Comment: why are you closing body and html tag before your logic of printing the data.

Comment: you must write echo '</body></html>';  after echo "</table>";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If logged in user shouldn't edit other user's posts, then don't show the edit column, then you can do simple if check for the column **Edit** like below

```
    while ($row_d = mysql_fetch_assoc($check_d)) {
        echo "<h1>Post made by: ".$row_d['username']."</h1>";
        $check_u = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM topics WHERE topic_creator='".$row_d['username']."'");
        while ($row_u = mysql_fetch_assoc($check_u)) {
            $id = $row_u['topic_id'];
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>".$row_u['topic_id']."</td>";
            echo "<td><a href='topic.php?id=$id'>".$row_u['topic_name']."<br /></a></td>";
            echo "<td>".$row_u['topic_creator']."<br /></td>";
            echo "<td>".$row_u['date']."<br /></td>";
// Add if condition here
            if($_SESSION['current_logged_in_user_id'] === $row_u['topic_creator_id']) {
                echo "<td><a href='edit.php?edit=$id'>Edit</a><br /></td>";
            }
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    }
```

but don't use mysql_* functions. use mysqli or PDOs for security reasons like protecting yourself from sql injection attacks.

Comment: Thank you sir!! Oh i did not know about the difference between mysql and mysqli. I will most certainly look into that! cheers