# PHP prevent URL input to delete row in database

Tags: php, session, get

I’m working on a blog website where the idea is that the current user that is logged in can edit and delete their own posts. I finally got it to work, but **my question is how I can prevent that a user can write the following input in the URL and do the same actions as my delete.php action.**

(Example) Manual URL input with topic_id:

/delete.php?del=133

Do anyone know how I can edit my existing code or know a better solution to the problem I will be much grateful!

This is how my code looks:

Profile.php:

[image]

```
if (@$_GET['id']) {
    $check_d = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id ='".$_GET['id']."'");

while ($row_d = mysql_fetch_assoc($check_d)) {
        echo "<div class='spacer'></div><h2 class='headertext'>Inlägg skapade av : ".$row_d['username']."</h2>";
        $check_u = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM topics WHERE topic_creator='".$row_d['username']."' ORDER BY topic_id DESC");
        while ($row_u = mysql_fetch_assoc($check_u)) {
            $id = $row_u['topic_id'];
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td class='postmain'><a href='topic.php?id=$id' class='links'>".$row_u['topic_name']."<br /></a></td>";
            echo "<td class='postmain'><p class='text'>".$row_u['topic_creator']."</p><br /></td>";
            echo "<td class='postmain'><p class='text'>".$row_u['date']."</p><br /></td>";

            if($_SESSION['username'] === $row_u['topic_creator']) {
                echo "<td class='postmain'><a href='edit.php?edit=$id'><button>Redigera</button></a>";
                echo "<a href='delete.php?del=$id'><button>Ta bort</button></a></td>";
            }
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    }
}
```

The highlighted code shows that only the current session (user) who made the post can edit and delete their own posts.

Delete.php:

[image]

```
if (isset($_GET['del'])) {

    //getting id of the data from url
    $id = $_GET['del'];

    //deleting the row from table
    $sql = "DELETE FROM topics WHERE topic_id='$id'";
    $res = mysql_query( $sql );

    //redirecting to the display page
    header("Location:admin.php");

}
```

Comment: You will have to check whether the user is the topic creator again in your delete.php. Also since you worry about your security your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection. You should use Prepared Statements.

Comment: You asked a similar question already https://stackoverflow.com/q/45817725/1415724 and accepted an answer. What's not working for the one you posted?

Comment: That question is related but not the same thing that I'm asking here. I want to know how I can prevent URL input to do the same thing as when i click the "delete" button on my page. @Fred-ii-

Comment: Hi, yes I know about the Prepare Statements. That's my next priority. I tried doing that with the same logic but it won't work. When I do an if statements in delete.php it doesn't work at all. // E @DimitrisFilippou

Comment: First check to see if the desired session array is set/not empty as per a logged in user, then use your `if (isset($_GET['del'])) {...}`, that's how it should be done. @erikos93

Answer (score 2):

Using isset function is solution here . The isset function will check that whether user clicked the delete/modify link or not(i.e he pasted delete.php directly in link) . So your code will only execute when user clicks the link .

```
if (isset($_GET['del']))
{
// your profile.php code here
}
else
{
// error message
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the same `$_SESSION` logic to ensure anyone accessing the `delete.php` has the appropriate permissions.

```
if (isset($_GET['del'])) {

    //getting id of the data from url
    $id = $_GET['del'];

    // Get the author for the specified post to ensure they are permitted to do so
    // TODO

    // Check that the author is the same as the $_SESSION user
    if($_SESSION['username'] === $postAuthor) {
        //deleting the row from table - FIX THIS (see below)
        $sql = "DELETE FROM topics WHERE topic_id='$id'";
        $res = mysql_query( $sql );
    } else {
        // User is not authorized, create error handling
        // TODO
    }

    //redirecting to the display page
    header("Location:admin.php");
}
```

Unrelated, *beware of SQL injection*. [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) is a good guide and you should not be using the `mysql_` functions and should be using prepared statements.

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't seem to work. Thanks for your answer though! @kchason